# Google Drive API license

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

We'd like to use Google Drive API in a server application.

We'd like to use functions related to document conversions in the Drive API.

The server is hosted in a Cloud-based environment, where additional server instances are added dynamically.

What is the proposed licence/pricing plan that we should use?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The google drive api is free to use there is no pricing plan.  As for liecencing you just have to agree to the normal Google developer [TOS](https://developers.google.com/terms) when you create a project.